# phpBB 3.2.3 How do I get gallery avatars to display at a specific width in the ACP?

Tags: css, gallery, administration, phpbb3, avatar

I was told that to do that in the UCP, I should add the following code to the end of phpBB3/styles/prosilver/theme/common.css

```
.gallery img {
 max-width: 189px;
 height: auto;
}
```

I thought I could do the same in the ACP by adding the same code to the end of phpBB3/adm/style/admin.css but it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It is that code but with one small difference. It should be

```
#gallery img {
 max-width: 189px;
 height: auto;
}
```

So a # at the beginning and not a .